# The equivalence of Matlab sprand() in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, random

I am trying to translate a Matlab code snippet into a Python one. However, I am not very sure how to correctly implement the `sprand()` function.

This is how the Matlab code use `sprand()`:

```
% n_z is an integer, n_dw is a matrix
n_p_z_dw = cell(n_z, 1); % n(d,w) * p(z|d,w)
for z = 1:n_z
  n_p_z_dw{z} = sprand(n_dw);
```

And this is how I implement the above logic in Python:

```
n_p_z_dw = [None]*n_z  # n(d,w) * p(z|d,w)
density = np.count_nonzero(n_dw)/float(n_dw.size)
for i in range(0, n_z):
    n_p_z_dw[i] = scipy.sparse.rand(n_d, n_w, density=density)
```

It seems to work, but I am not very sure about this. Any comment or suggestion?

Comment: I'm pretty sure these are different. `sprand(S)` gives uniformly distributed random numbers with the same sparsity structure as S. `scipy.sparse.rand(a,b,density=density)` has the random numbers have a density of density, equivalent to `sprand(a,b,density)`.

Comment: @cge Yes, I know that, so that's the best thing I can do to mimic sprand(). So I am still looking for a better way to implement `sprand(S)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should be a relatively fast way, I think, for a sparse array A:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import numpy as np
sparse.coo_matrix((np.random.rand(A.nnz),A.nonzero()),shape=A.shape)
```

This will construct a COO format sparse matrix: it uses `A.nonzero()` as the coordinates, and `A.nnz` (the number of nonzero entries in A) to find the number of random numbers to generate.

---

I wonder, though, whether this might be a useful addition to the `scipy.sparse.rand` function.